# Allocation of large pinned memory chunk using CUDA with Java

Tags: java, memory-management, cuda, jcuda

I'm implementing GPU calculation in a program already written in Java. For that purpose I'm using [jcuda](http://www.jcuda.de/) bindings.
I need a fast host to device memory transfer of, sometimes, relatively large arrays. If I want to use streams, I have to use pinned memory. The problem is if I want to allocate host pinned memory larger than cca 600 Mbs of RAM, I get "CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY" exception.
This is the code I used to test size of the available pinned memory:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Init GPU
    JCudaDriver.setExceptionsEnabled(true);

    // Initialize the device and create device context
    cuInit(0);
    CUdevice device = new CUdevice();
    cuDeviceGet(device, 0);
    CUcontext context = new CUcontext();
    cuCtxCreate(context, 0, device);

    Pointer p = new Pointer();

    int Kb = 1024;
    int Mb = 1024 * Kb;
    int Gb = 1024 * Mb;
    int sequenceSize = 172*Mb; // times 4 for float
    float[] expecteds = new float[sequenceSize];
    float[] actuals = new float[sequenceSize];
    Arrays.fill(expecteds, 3.33f);
    int i = 0;
    try {
        JCudaDriver.cuMemAllocHost(p, sequenceSize* Sizeof.FLOAT);
        FloatBuffer fb = p.getByteBuffer(0, sequenceSize* Sizeof.FLOAT).
                order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).
                asFloatBuffer();

        fb.position(0);
        fb.put(expecteds);
        fb.position(0);
        fb.get(actuals);
        JCudaDriver.cuMemFreeHost(p);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JCudaDriver.cuMemFreeHost(p);
    }

}
```

Now, I'm aware that OS can prevent me to use too much pinned memory since it's non-pageable. The thing is that I have 48Gb (45Gb free) of physical memory and I need a way of forcing OS to give me more of it. Is there a way to do this (elegantly if possible)?

EDIT: OS is 64-bit Windows 7 Professional SP1

Comment: Are you sure you are using main memory and not memory on the device?

Comment: Well, [cuMemAllocHost()](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MEM_gdd8311286d2c2691605362c689bc64e0.html) function is used to allocate host memory, and in example I gave I don't touch device memory. As for OS, I'm currently on 64-bit Windows 7 Professional SP1

Comment: I recommend you allocate the memory by other means (say, a thin wrapper around VirtualAlloc()), then use cuMemHostRegister()/cuMemHostUnregister() to make it available to CUDA.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I'm using Java 6u35 windows x64.

Comment: There's a known bug in NVIDIA drivers that makes it fail if it can't use memory addresses below somewhere around 2 GB, so try to limit Java's heap to maybe 1 GB with something like `java -Xmx1G`.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware I've tried with VirtualAlloc() and cudaHostRegister() in C++, but I still can't register more than 686 Mbs. code: `void * p = VirtualAlloc( NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE );` `cudaHostRegister(p, size, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are running Java in 64-bit mode. The [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html) suggests the [default is 32-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_selection), even with the 64-bit downloads. The linked FAQ also tells you how to run in 64-bit mode, you'll need to use the 64-bit DLLs etc. too.

@ArchaeSoftware's suggestion of using `cuMemHostRegister()`/`cuMemHostUnregister()` to pin smaller sections of the memory is a sensible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It  seems an old page but without Answer..
I guess you are not utilizing your RAM properly as by default Java does not allocate much memory for heap by itself. You can force JVM to use minimum and maximum memory by -Xms and -Xmx respectively and as you are working on 64-bit architechture use "-d64" to after "-Xms" or "-Xmx"